# OppRecordCombo: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors ()

Tags: exception, error-handling, salesforce

I have created a trigger on the Opportunity object for before insert and before update, through which I am sending the Trigger.newMap variable as an argument to my apex class where I am checking the existence of a particular combination against the records in another Object called record combinations and trying to add an error, if a particular pattern of record doesn't exist. But when I try to create an Opportunity or update it I am getting the below exception.

```
OppRecordCombo: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors ()
```

My trigger is below

```
trigger OppRecordCombo on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    if((Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) || (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate)) {
        OppRecordComboClass opp = new OppRecordComboClass();
        opp.checkComboValidate(Trigger.newMap);
    }
}
```

And my apex class is as below

```
public without sharing class OppRecordComboClass {
    //private List<Opportunity> opportunities;
    String recordComboString;
    String oppComboString;
    List<String> recordComboStringList = new List<String>();

    public OppRecordComboClass() {
    }

    public void checkComboValidate(Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunities) {
        try {
            List<Record_Combination__c> recordcombo = [SELECT Client__r.Name,
                                                            Client_SFDC_ID__c,
                                                            Agency__r.Name,
                                                            Agency_SFDC_ID__c
                                                            FROM Record_Combination__c];

            for(Record_Combination__c recComb : recordcombo) {
                recordComboString = recComb.Client__r.Name + recComb.Client_SFDC_ID__c + recComb.Agency__r.Name + recComb.Agency_SFDC_ID__c;
                recordComboStringList.add(recordComboString);
            }

            List<Opportunity> oppCheckList = [SELECT Id,
                                                    Account.Name,
                                                    AccountId,
                                                    Agency_Name__r.Name,
                                                    Agency_Name__c,
                                                    Allow_New_Account_Combination__c
                                                    FROM Opportunity
                                                    WHERE Id in :opportunities.keySet()];

            for(Opportunity opp : oppCheckList) {
                if(opp.Allow_New_Account_Combination__c == false) {
                    oppComboString = opp.Account.Name + opp.AccountId + opp.Agency_Name__r.Name + opp.Agency_Name__c;
                    System.debug('This is the opp combo string akki ' + oppComboString);
                    if(!recordComboStringList.contains(oppComboString)) {
                        //Opportunity triggerOpp = opportunities.get(opp.Id);
                        opportunities.get(opp.Id).addError('This Customer and Agency combination doesn\'t exist in OB. Do you still want to create this Opportunity');
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('An exception occured at the line ' + e.getLineNumber() + ' exception is ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please let me know why is this happening and how can this be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't pass `trigger.newMap` to your method. This variable is `Map<Id, Opportunity>` and [when you are `before insert` ids don't exist yet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) (well, duh). You don't have keys for the map so the variable will be empty and your logic will be skipped. Pass `trigger.new` instead.
2. Don't `SELECT ... FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : ...`. You have the "new" state of data right there, passed from trigger. If you query you'll get old data from before this save operation, not what the user edited right now. Or nothing (because if you're `before insert` - stuff doesn't exist in database yet). Work on the original, on `trigger.new`.
3. You cannot `addError()` on something you queried. It's not changing right now. The `FinalException` is not a great name but it tells you to put `addError` on elements of `trigger.new`

Comment: In the trigger context I don't get the details of parent and child entity right? For example I wanted the Account.Name, where account is the lookup field, which won't get passed in the Trigger.New context. Hence I had to query it separately. Is there any work around for it?

Comment: loop through trigger.new, collect `Opportunity.AccountId` to a `Set<Id>`. Outside of loop make `Map<Id, Account> accs = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :ids]);`. Loop through trigger.new again and reference them, `String accName = accs.get(opp.AccountId);`

Comment: You don't really need that though, do you? In your reference data you're also making relationship query. Your key can have ids instead of names `0019E00001JLRluQAH;ABC001;a119E000002ObwYQAS`. Won't look as sexy in debug log but better performance and simpler code. If you have 2 accounts with same name and only one of them is in allowed combinations - would you expect opportunity for the other one to go through? ;)

Comment: The 1st or 2nd comment? Because if you decided to go with 2nd one, if it works great wit IDs, not names - now would be good moment to go back to the original VLOOKUP idea and possibly scrap this whole thing :P

Comment: I am actually working the 2nd comment right now. I'll also try looking into and work on VLOOKUP too as you mentioned.